# Creation of entity in JPA which has a joinColumn

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one, joincolumn

I am trying to create a entity B which has a Join column with another entity A with the other entity's primary key. When I create an entity B with a value that is not in entity A, **I am not seeing an exception**. Should this not be automatically taken care by JPA?

Code snippets of the entities:

```
 @Entity
    public class A{

        @Id
        @Column(name="ORIGIN_ID")
        private long id;
        ...

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="aBean",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        private List<B> bList;
    }


    @Entity
    public class B{
        @Id
        private long id;
        ...

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinColumn(name="ORIGIN_ID")
        private A aBean;
    }
```

Comment: Please paste a code snippet on how do you "create" entity B.

Comment: For creation, with the passed id, I am getting a bean of entity A and then setting the bean to Entity B's aBean object.For now I am adding a null check while setting the bean object as a solution to the above problem

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the management of relations. There is nothing in the JPA spec that I can remember that requires an exception to be thrown there (because the user has passed in inconsistent relation information). All JPA implementations will have their own handling of the situation. Some will only persist what is at the owner side of the relation. Others will persist based on what is encountered first. Others have optional handling that can be turned on to detect such things and flag them up to the user

Simplest advice is when using bidirectional relations, make sure that both sides are consistent.

Comment: Thank you. This scenario was part of some negative scenario testing. Just wanted to check if there was some solution